How do mathematical operations between two iterators work in C++?
I'm new to C++ and trying to understand iterators. So far I have come to understand that iterators are like pointers that can be used to traverse through elements of a linear data structure. But I have difficulty understanding mathematical operations on iterators. I have already understood the increment/decrement operators, or operation between an iterator and a number. For an iterator it :

it++ or it+1 means the iterator will point to the next element.
it-- or it-1 means the iterator will point to the previous element.

But I'm having trouble wrapping my head around mathematical operations between two iterators. For example, in this code here:
vector<int> preorder {1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 3, 6, 9};
vector<int> inorder {4, 2, 7, 5, 8, 1, 3, 9, 6};
auto mid = find(inorder.begin(), inorder.end(), preorder[0]) - inorder.begin();

I know that find(inorder.begin(), inorder.end(), preorder[0]) will return an iterator pointing to the element 1 in inorder, but I don't know what the result will be after inorder.begin() is subtracted from it, and why is it subtracted at all?
Please help me understand how mathematical operations between two iterators work. Thanks :)
I tried searching on Google what would be the result of mathematical operations being performed between two iterators, but sadly I couldn't find any credible answer.

What does it - vector.begin() actually do? and What are the benefits of std::distance over subtracting iterators? and How does subtracting X.begin() return the index of an iterator? and How does the subtraction of two iterators denote the index of a vector item

It's worth pointing out that std::distance is an alternative to subtracting iterators.

"iterators are like pointers"  It is actually the other way round, pointers are a kind of iterators.

@BoP but pointers came first.  I think the early implementations of the STL often used pointers as iterators.

std::vector iterators are random-access iterators. They can be freely incremented and decremented by any number to jump directly to any element in the vector.
Given 2 random-access iterators into the same container, you can simply subtract the earlier one from the later one to get the number of elements that are between them.
In your example, the code is using this trait to calculate the index of the element that the found iterator refers to.

Thanks, but I have a question: if find(inorder.begin(), inorder.end(), preorder[0]) - inorder.begin() gives the number of elements between the two iterators, then is the mid variable an integer and not an iterator?

@SudhanshuTiwari That is correct. More specifically, in this example, the mid variable is deduced to be a vector::difference_type, which is usually std::ptrdiff_t, which is a signed integer large enough to hold the difference of subtracting 2 pointer values.

inorder.begin() points to the first element of the vector.
find(inorder.begin(), inorder.end(), preorder[0]) will give you an iterator to the found item, or the inorder.end() iterator if no item is found.
So, if we subtract the beginning iterator from the returned iterator then we get how many times you would have to increment the begin iterator to reach the returned iterator (a distance).  This gives you the position/index of the element in the vector.
If the end iterator is returned then the position would be the same as the size of the vector and vector[size] is an invalid location.
